# Convert Unix Time to IST in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I use the below method to convert Unix Time stored in the `hltime` column of a MySQL DB to a readable format - "YYYY DD MM hh:mm:ss"

For Example:

- UTC date and time stored format in MySQL DB: `1500473820`
- MySQL Function used to convert to readable format:

  ```
  from_unixtime(hltime,'%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s')
  ```
- Result: "2017 19th July 07:47:00"

The date and time stored in the `hltime` column are in GMT. Thus how could I use the `from_unixtime()` function (or any other function) to convert the values shown into IST (Indian Standard Time).

I have tried using `convert_tz(from_unixtime(hltime,'%Y-%D-%M %h:%i:%s'),'+00:00','+06:00')`, but I get `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date time format used to convert is not correct

**Change**:

```
'%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s'
```

**To**:

```
'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'
```

And it should be working

**Example**:

```
SELECT @ut:= 1500473820 AS ut
     , @ts:=FROM_UNIXTIME(@ut,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') AS gmt
     , CONVERT_TZ(CAST( @ts AS DATETIME ),'+00:00','+05:30') AS ist;
```

**Result**:

```
----------  -------------------  ---------------------
        ut  gmt                  ist                  
----------  -------------------  ---------------------
1500473820  2017-07-19 07:47:00  2017-07-19 13:17:00
```